# Mongo query giving unexpected results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can anyone tell me why this query would return this record?

query:

```
db.sales.findOne({"qualified": true, created_at: {$gte:1334534400}, campaign: {$exists:1}})
```

record:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4f8b6ef8da45bb3e600001fe"),
        "grand_total" : 9.99,
        "order_id" : "T003974723",
        "items" : [
                {
                        "price" : 9.99,
                        "id" : "23958754",
                        "name" : "UO Daisy Sunglasses",
                        "qty" : 1
                }
        ],
        "created_at" : 1334537675,
        "visitor_id" : "1332652531389",
        "unique_session_id" : "i-0f7e196e-110800",
        "session_id" : "i-0f7e196e-110800",
        "qualified" : true,
        "needler_id" : 357,
        "ip_address" : "76.103.214.29",
        "in_session" : true
}
```

I THOUGHT I was asking mongo to give me back a record that had 'campaign' was a property.  However, as you can see, this record has no property called 'campaign'

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?  Apparently using **$exists: 1** (instead of **$exists: true** is only supported from v1.9 on.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2322

Comment: awesome, put this as an answer so I can accept it.  our servers were using 1.8 while my workstation has 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of mongodb are you using?  Apparently using **$exists: 1** (instead of **$exists: true** is only supported from v1.9 on:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2322

Comment: @AlW no prob!  Glad I could help.